# "Intentionally awkward" Usage Guidance text for some tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not sure how many tags follow this pattern, but I just noticed these two:

- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-mode
- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-agenda

They both omit the tag name/title from the Usage Guidance text, instead starting:

- "is an Emacs major mode for keeping notes ..."
- "is the Org mode facility that generates agenda views ..."

I can see the intention behind the pattern, but it doesn't work for the UIs I'm looking at.

If I hover over a tag, the tag name isn't repeated at the top of the pop-up, so I'm left reading a sentence which is missing its beginning.

If I visit the 'questions' links above, we get:

> ### Questions tagged [org-mode]
>
> is an Emacs major mode for keeping notes

Which is different, but just as bad.

It seems clear to me that the Usage Guidance text needs to start with either the tag name or a 'friendly' version thereof (such as "Org Mode" instead of "org-mode").